# Validation Application Block - How to use validation metada class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library, modelmetadata, validation-application-bl, metadatatype

I'm using VAB to validate some classes with attributes and I'm using a metadata class to share the same validation among different classes.
When i try to validate an object in the controller (btw i'm using asp.net mvc) the `ValidationResults` does not have errors and my entity should not be valid.
But, ASP.NET MVC does his magic because `ModelState.IsValid` is false. I guess the problem is the way I'm doing the manual validations.

In Global.asax I'm loading the associations between the classes and metadata classes.

Global.ASAX

```
private static void RegisterMetadataExtensions()
{
    AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider typeDescriptionProvider;

    typeDescriptionProvider =
        new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
            typeof(FooViewModel), typeof(FooMetadata));

    TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(typeDescriptionProvider,
        typeof(FooViewModel));

    typeDescriptionProvider =
        new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(
            typeof(FooCommand), typeof(FooMetadata));

    TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
        typeDescriptionProvider, typeof(FooCommand));
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Action(FooViewModel vm)
{
    Validator<FooViewModel> validator =
        ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<FooViewModel>();

    ValidationResults res = validator.Validate(vm);

    //res.Count is 0
```

OR

```
    ValidationResults res = Validation.Validate<FooViewModel>(vm);

    //res.Count is 0

    //ModelState.IsValid is false
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
```

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the enterprise library, but I think a better way to do validation with MVC is to make your ViewModel implement `IValidatableObject`. That way, it automatically gets validated during the binding phase that sets `ModelState.Isvalid`

Comment: You don't know the OPs requirements, so you can't advice DataAnnotations. VAB has many features and extension points that DataAnnotations doesn't have, such as configuration based validation and the possibility to build (attributeless) code based configuration.

Comment: I know that a) he's using attributes, and b) a metadata class, because I have read the question. That is why I made this *suggestion*

Answer (score 0):

For your VAB validator to hook into ASP.NET MVC's validation I think you would need to implement ModelValidatorProvider and wrap the VAB validation results as described here ... http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/enterprise-library-validation-example-for-aspnet-mvc-2.html